# Run arbitrary lines in same debugging session like Spyder?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm wondering if there is a way to setup VS Code to debug like you can in Spyder or closer to a Jupyter or ipython notebook where you can run some block or line of code (with F9 in Spyder) and that code is interpreted and the debugging session is still 'live' if you will.

In VS code I can't seem to run any block of code and then run another block of code in the same session without stopping and starting up another debugging session.

I tend to like to load a bunch of data and then execute arbitrary lines of code after that as i figure out what i want to do with it.

Comment: I know Atom has the Hydrogen plugin which is like Jupyter within it, but I've yet to find a VSCode equivalent

Comment: I don't think there's anything currently available for VSCode to enable you to do this yet. I generally just boot up the file in ipython

Comment: Yes there is a Jupyter extension for VScode. Install this extension and make first line of code #%%. Above that character set a run code label appears enabling user to run code in place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been added to VS Code:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in the command palette to do this. With your python code open select lines you want to run. Then go to view menu and select command palette. There is a command that says, Python: Run selection/line in Python terminal.  This will run just what you select and print out any outputs.

Comment: The issue with this approach is it doesn't seem to allow for additional lines to be run from the same debugging session.